# Bootstrap navbar-fixed-top

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create bootstrap navbar-fixed-top menu with bootstrap. I have followed and tried alot of tutorials online, but I always end up having the same problem with small 1px lines between the buttons and between the navbar and the content. The lines between the buttons changes depending on the width of the browser and the vertical one depends on the zoom of the window. It seems to be a general problem since i also experience a lot of these lines between containers on smartphone depending on zoom and scroll position. The only way i can get rid of them is by making weird margins so everything is placed on top of each other. Do anybody now what the cause might be?

[image of the problem](http://postimg.org/image/6qbkz152f/)

Comment: I've not encountered this using Bootstrap, you haven't posted your own CSS and an example, so there's no way of knowing. I would guess that the bottom line is the bottom border found on the navbar-fixed-top (see the unpacked CSS). Use the examples on GetBootstrap.com getting starting page getbootstrap.com/examples/ to learn from, other sources don't keep up with changes

Comment: I will post my code and maybe a video when i get home from work. I have search all over the web and have not encountered similair problem, so I am probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is a border being added to the `<li>` elements in the navbar perhaps?

Try adding this CSS to your own custom CSS and make sure it comes after Bootstraps CSS

```
.navbar-nav>li {
    border: 0px !important;
}
```